# jQuery How do I move an element inside of another element

Tags: jquery, css, grails, menu, list

Hi I'm using grails navigation plugin and when it generates menus it put the sub navigation underneath the main menu, but i'm making my menu a vertical menu so i don't want the sub menu under the whole menu i want it under the active element.

Example: this is how it generate the menu and sub menu

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="submenu">
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

What i want is:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
   <li>item1
     <ul class="submenu">
       <li>item1</li>
       <li>item2</li>
       <li>item3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Since i don't know of a way to make grails nav plugin do this i guess i'll have to make jquery do it after it's generated. Any ideas?

---

Edit

So the jquery i used from the answer below is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
        alert("hi");
        $(".subnavigation").appendTo($(".navigation li:navigation_active"));
      });
</script>
....
<ul class="navigation" id="navigation_tabs">
    <li class="navigation_first">Item 1</li>
    <li class="navigation_active">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li class="navigation_last">Item 5</li>
</ul> 
<ul class="subnavigation" id="subnavigation_tabs">
    <li class="subnavigation_first">Sub 1</li>
    <li>Sub 2</li>
    <li class="subnavigation_last">Sub 3</li>
</ul>
```

This seems like it should work but the menu still looks the same with all the sub items down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".submenu").appendTo($(".mainmenu li:first"));
```

Alternatively:

```
$(".mainmenu li:first").append($(".submenu"));
```

Or, to put it under all of them (hide by CSS):

```
$(".mainmenu li").append($(".submenu"));
```

**Edit**, for the updated question:

```
$(".subnavigation").appendTo($(".navigation li.navigation_active"));
```

Comment: I used your code it seemed correct but didn't work. I edited my post to show what i have.

Comment: @TripWired - Change this: `$(".subnavigation").appendTo($(".navigation li:navigation_active"));` to this: `$(".subnavigation").appendTo($(".navigation li.navigation_active"));`  The `navigation_active` part is a class, which you prefix with a `.`, `:first` is a pseudo-class, a bit difference.

Comment: Oh duh i should have seen that. Thanks for the help works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming with active you mean mouse hovering.

```
$("ul.mainmenu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).append($("ul.submenu"))
})
```